# ruby on rails: ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Bignum into String) when use form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, actionview

I have a problem with `form_for` on Ruby on Rails, using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0.0.

I followed [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-signup_form), everything went perfect until i added the `form_for`. When I open the sign up page, it throws:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Bignum into String):
    3: 
    4: <div class="row">
    5:   <div class="span6 offset3">
    6:     <%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
    7: 
    8:       <%= f.label :name %>
    9:       <%= f.text_field :name %>
  app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___700836681490305320_18582480'
```

This is my app/views/users/new.html.erb

```ruby
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password %>
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
            <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is my  app/views/users/new.html.erb <% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Can you please edit the original question, add the form, and format it as code so there is syntax highlighting.  It is very hard to read the comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and it ended up being related to SSL, and how I had stored the secret token in /initializers/secret_token.rb, since this code gets run prior to generating a form.

Check to see that your secret token is a hex number stored as a string.

should look like

RailsApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'abcdef01234567890'

Comment: Yupp, that one bit me too. 
It should also be noted that you can have rails generate a good secret for you with
`:$ rake secret`

Comment: it should also be noted that this is not the usual way for ruby to store hex values, and I don't believe it would hurt if rails itself accepted both a hex value and a valid hex valued string.